# Scaling and Rotation Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Write the Matrix
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
as the product of a scaling matrix with factor |λ| and a rotation matrix with angle φ. Find |λ| and φ
for which −π < φ < π.

How would I express this matrix as a scaling and rotation matrix in terms of λ and φ? I'm not sure how to approach this question.

Comment: Multiply a rotation matrix by $\varphi$ and a scaling matrix by a factor $|\lambda|$ together and compare element by element.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=\sqrt2\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&-\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}=\sqrt2\begin{bmatrix}\cos \frac{\pi}{4}&-\sin \frac{\pi}{4}\\\sin \frac{\pi}{4}&\cos \frac{\pi}{4}\end{bmatrix}$$